# How does Stack Overflow SEO work?

Tags: discussion, google

I found a Stack Overflow question in Google search results which was posted just 2 minutes before.

I just want to know how Stack Overflow SEO works.

Comment: Google indexes Stack Overflow very frequently. That's it.

Comment: It's not really something on SO's end. It's the fact that Google chooses to index SO very fast. Why? Probably b.c they think it's a great site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stack-overflow

Comment: According to a 2011 article, [google indexes Stack Overflow 10 times a second](http://www.businessinsider.com/google-stackoverflow-2011-3).  More on that over on MSE: [How does StackOverflow get indexed by Google in such as fast manner?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98083/213963) which is a duplicate of [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9726/213963).  Note also the many [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9726?lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google most probably indexes Stack Overflow as quickly as they do on account of the amount of new content that keeps coming up quickly on the site.

Consider that it normally takes a couple of minutes for a new question to drop off the home page - consider how many answers and comments have been posted within such a time period on Stack Overflow and you would see that it makes sense to keep up with this speed by indexing quickly and continuously.

When you have a site where content moves (added and updated) fast and which according to their algorithms is high quality, it makes sense to keep up with the updated and new content.